# How to redirect the page from authentication page of Google when Cancel is given?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console, google-developer-tools

I've implemented google drive in my webpage. I need the users to authenticate their google accounts before using it. During that authentication screen, when I give "Cancel" button, error occurs. How to redirect the page to parent window when "Cancel" button is given?

[image: This is the image of authentication]

Comment: When the cancel button was pushed, the result is feedbacked to the redirect uri with the query parameter. If the redirect uri is ``http://localhost``, the result is returned to ``http://localhost?error=access_denied``. So you can do the redirect by retrieving ``error=access_denied``. In order to use this, a server to retrieve the value as the redirect uri is required.  If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Welcome. Thank you, too.